# Sort date in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I want to select the dates in ascending order. Dates are stored in `dd-MMM-yy`(02-Mar-12) format. Here is my query:

```
SELECT EventDate,Event,ID from EventCalenderTable Order By EventDate ASC
```

output is:

```
10-03-12
12-02-12
15-01-12
18-07-12
```

But the output should like:

```
15-01-12
12-02-12
10-03-12
18-07-12
```

Event Date is date datatype.

I have seen number of post about storing date in sql. I noticed that `Convert` function done the tricks in sql server. But how can I do this in Sqlite??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

SQLite only knows three [date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html):

- Text ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS")
- Real Julian day numbers since November 24, 4714 B.C
- Integer number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC

SQLite does have [five date/time functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) for converting between formats.

Comment: Yup. You need to store your data with one of these formats, or else all you have is text. In designing a database, you don't need the stored format to be the same as the original input or final output format. They are separate things.